# How can I delete test transactions from Google Wallet?

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-pay

I'm implementing in-App billing in an Android App using v3 and IabHelper.

I can fetch the list of available products and complete a purchase.

In order to avoid having to make a new product every time I want to test purchase, I'd like to simply be able to delete completed test purchases so I can re-purchase them.

How on earth can I delete test purchases from Google Wallet? Looking at the interface, it appears that there's no way to do this which seems shocking at best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete purchases by going to your orders page, selecting the test purchase and then selecting the "Refund" button in the right hand corner.